# I want to Convert a C++ code to vb.net

Tags: vb.net

This is the code for testing my shell-code in c++, I tried to convert it with a program but it didn't work,Thanks in advance for the answers

```
enter code here
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{

int (*ret)();


ret = (int(*)())shellcode;  
     (int)(*ret)();             
}
```

and this is the resulted code when i use a program to convert but it didnt work in my visual studio 2010:

enter code here

```
Imports System

Shared Sub Main(ByVal args() As String)

enter code here
'C++ TO VB CONVERTER TODO TASK: This delegate declaration (converted from the original            function pointer) must be moved outside of this method:


Private Delegate Function retDelegate() As Integer ' ret is a function pointer



Dim ret As retDelegate



ret = ()shellcode ' ret points to our shellcode
                               ' shellcode is type caste as a function 
CInt(Math.Truncate(ret())) ' execute, as a function, shellcode[]

End Sub
```

Comment: The latest build of C++ to VB Converter fixes this - (include the declaration for 'shellcode' for the best conversion).

Comment: This is the latest one already

Comment: No - it's not. The latest (yesterday) always moves the delegate declaration instead of showing the message.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just call shellcode right away? Instead of getting it's pointer and calling it through the pointer.

If you want to do something similar in VB.NET it'll look like this.

```
Function Func() As Integer

    Return 1
End Function

Delegate Function FuncDelegate() As Integer

Sub Main()

    Dim ret As FuncDelegate

    ret = AddressOf Func
    Console.WriteLine(ret())

End Sub
```